# How do I return the value from my request in this function? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, axios, promise

I'm new to Javascript and try to make something where I make a request with Axios inside a function. I want the function to return the result I get from axios, so I can use that in other parts of my code. How would I archieve this? Right now the function get_def is not returning any value, so result will be undefined

```
function get_def(word) {
    axios.get(`myapi`)
    .then(function (response) {
        return response
    })
}

var result = get_def("test")
// do other stuff with the var
```

I tried the above code and expected the result to be the response I get from axios, but its undefined instead

Comment: Your function get_def doesn't return anything. Also you should use promises or async/await behaviour to wait for the axios method to finish returning the response.